# How to configure OpenVPN with the following restrictions?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, configuration-managment

I initially set up OpenVPN on a Pi [using PiVPN](https://github.com/pivpn/pivpn) because the official Guidelines/Tutorial seemed a little too technical to me.

Now, I'd like to expand the VPN capabilities.

Again, I read about [scope](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/#scope) and [policies](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/#configuring-client-specific-rules-and-access-policies) on the OpenVPN site.

*The goal:*

Sort of similar to what they describe in the policies section. Except that I already have a "working" OpenVPN server instance and some clients.

For the sake of simplicity, see the following table which should clarify my intention:

```
╔══════════╦══════════════════╦═════════════════════════════╦════════════════╗
║  Class   ║ Virtual IP Range ║     Allowed LAN Access      ║  Common Names  ║
╠══════════╬══════════════════╬═════════════════════════════╬════════════════╣
║ Regular  ║ 10.8.0.0/24      ║ Custom service at 10.66.4.4 ║ Custom service ║
║ Advanced ║ 10.8.1.0/24      ║ Entire 10.66.4.0/24 subnet  ║ Advanced       ║
╚══════════╩══════════════════╩═════════════════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Where "custom service" is a local server that provides some telephony service.

How would I configure my server (OpenVPN server configuration file) to achieve the above result?

I'd like to leave the client configuration untouched if possible.

I don't care to much about the Virtual IP Range - if necessary, these values may be changed.

This is how my current configuration looks like:

```
dev tun
proto udp
port 42917
ca /etc/ca.crt
cert /etc/xxx.crt
key /etc/xxx.key
dh none
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
# Set your primary domain name server address for clients
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
push "block-outside-dns"
# Override the Client default gateway by using 0.0.0.0/1 and
# 128.0.0.0/1 rather than 0.0.0.0/0. This has the benefit of
# overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway.
push "redirect-gateway def1"
client-to-client
keepalive 1800 3600
remote-cert-tls client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-crypt /etc/ta.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
status-version 3
syslog
verb 3
#DuplicateCNs allow access control on a less-granular, per user basis.
#Remove # if you will manage access by user instead of device. 
#duplicate-cn
# Generated for use by PiVPN.io
```

Comment: All clients should have the same access for this 2 networks? What is the current client configuration?

Comment: So in what way is "policies" not fulfilling your need? I'm not sure if I see a concrete question or problem here. Anyway, for cases like this, I might just run multiple server instances for simplicity (and hence, with the subnet topology). Then it would be all about firewalling.

Comment: @Yehuda I'm not sure whether I got you right; there should be two types of users - "regular" and "advanced", where "regular" users only have access to the custom service. The current configuration is the default PiVPN configuration, I'll add the file to my question.